# Different weights for datasets tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run this piece of code:

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([2,2,2,2])
d = [a, b]
weights = [0.2, 0.8]
res = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(d, weights=weights)
for elem in res:
  print(elem)
```

And get the result:

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

That confused me. I thought it should be a downsampling for both datasets `a` and `b`. And I should get a result like `[1,1,2,2,2]` instead of containing all the original elements since it should be 0.2 * len(a) + 0.8 * len(b). Did I misunderstand the weighted sampling?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like a bug. You can raise bug [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new/choose). Thanks!